# How to set SRX rule to break both before and after a character

Tags: regex, text-segmentation

I am updating an SRX rules file using the SRX specification [www.ttt.org/oscarstandards/srx/srx10.html](http://www.ttt.org/oscarstandards/srx/srx10.html)

There is no explicit mention of how to make a break both before *and* after a certain text.

In a document the bullet character `\u2022` appears and in needs to be in its own segment, thus there needs to be a break both before and after.

The only solution I came up with is:

```
<rule break="yes">
    <afterbreak>\u2022</afterbreak>
</rule>
<rule break="yes">
    <beforebreak>\u2022</beforebreak>
</rule>
```

Is this a correct syntax?

Comment: Yes, it says it supports `\uXXXX` entities. Although it also says it supports `\x{XXXX}`, too, so you may as well use `\x{2022}`

Comment: Did you try your rules before posting the question?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately this was for a remote server and I had no possibility to test it before deploying. I took a blind shot, and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [*1.2. Regular Expressions* section, *1.2.1. Metacharacters* table](http://www.ttt.org/oscarstandards/srx/srx10.html#Intro_Enc):

> `\uhhhh`    Match the character with the hex value hhhh. 
>   ...
>   `\x{hhhh}`    Match the character with hex value hhhh 
>   `\xhh`    Match the character with two digit hex value hh

You may use any of the three notations, but I guess you may just keep you SRX rules as it.

Comment: As a note, what the documentation does not cover is how to segment the same line twice, in this case both before and after the bullet character. So in such instances I have to first put a break before it, thus the first rule must be the <afterbreak> rule and then the second rule is that we put a break after it, otherwise the bullet comes before the break, with the <beforebreak> rule. Maybe you also want to edit this into your answer to make it all-inclusive.